# wordpress: I want to add cookies popup on my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, cookies

I have added cookies popup on my wordpress site, and it appears on all the pages, I want to make sure, cookies popup won't appear on privacy-policy page.
I'm using the plugin cookie notice to add cookies on my site.
please suggest how i can make sure cookies popup won't appear on privacy policy page

Comment: Can you please share the link of the plugin here

Comment: plugin link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/cookie-notice/

Comment: It seems there is no setting provided by plugin where you can conditionally show cookie notice to the page.
So, Now there should two ways you can achieve your requirement. First you can hide the cookie notice by identifying the current page url/slug is equal to privacy-policy page url/slug and hide or show the cookie notice accordingly using javascript. Second, add custom cookie notice instead using plugin if you are having good knowledge of javscript.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in `functions.php` file and **replace page id** with `privacy policy` page id.

```
 function disable_cookie_notify( $output, $options ) {
   if(is_page(2)){
    $output = '';
   }
   return $output;
}
add_filter( 'cn_cookie_notice_output', 'disable_cookie_notify', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Glad to help you.